# Power BI Age Restrictions

Tags: powerbi

I am using a table of mass data that needs to be sorted.

When the data comes in it is assigned the date it arrived, I need to figure out how many days old it is in a new column.
Say there was an entry on 12/20/2017 - I need to figure out how many days old it is, and assign it a specific ID Number.

Comment: a data sample and an example of a desired result would be helpful.

Comment: Sunday, February 17th, 2016 
If data is 0-30 days old, assign month
If data is 31-60 days old, assign 2month
If data is 61-90 days old, assign 3month
If data is 91-365 days old, assign ABC123